# Pass picasso into listview

Tags: android, picasso, listadapter

i can't "pass Picasso" to the adapter. i have to create my own custom adapter. It may even be based on the SimpleAdapter. Like this:

aldigim_profil_URL is image URL

```
 public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.getTag();
        if (img == null) {
            img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.alinan_list_profil_url);
            v.setTag(img);
        }

        String url_test ="http://" + aldigim_profil_URL.toString();
        // get the url from the data you passed to the `Map`
        String url = ((Map)getItem(position)).get(url_test);
        // do Picasso
        Picasso.with(v.getContext()).load(url).into(img);

        // return the view
        return v;
    }
}
```

and my listadapter is like this;

contactList is return image url list from Json Websercive

```
        ListAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), contactList,
                R.layout.activity_list_alinan_gorevler, new String[]{"Gorevi_Veren", "Gorev_Adi", "Tarih"},
                new int[]{R.id.alinan_list_gorev_veren, R.id.alinan_list_gorev_adi, R.id.alinan_list_tarih});
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and my error is

String url = ((Map)getItem(position)).get(url_test);

> Error:(287, 54) error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Add your Map class code to better understand. This error seems to getItem(Pos).get(url) not returning string type. Check Map.get(url) return string type in Map class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.getTag();
        if (img == null) {
            img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.alinan_list_profil_url);
            v.setTag(img);
        }

        String url_test ="http://" + aldigim_profil_URL.toString();
        // get the url from the data you passed to the `Map`
        String url = ((Map)getItem(position)).get(TAG_IMAGE);

        // do Picasso
        Picasso.with(v.getContext()).load(url).into(img);

        // return the view
        return v;
    }
 }
```